# Strange geometry shader program behavior...GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

This geometry program is part of my B T N visualizer shader.
It works fine in mode 1.. BUT and there always seems to be one...
The tangent and bi-tangent sections never are hit if mode <> 1?

```
#version 120

#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : enable         

uniform int mode;
uniform float l_length;

varying in vec3 n[];
varying in vec3 t[];
varying in vec3 b[];
varying vec4 color;

void main()
{
    vec4 sumV;
    vec4 sumN;

    // Normal
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    if (mode == 1)
    {
        sumV = (gl_PositionIn[0] + gl_PositionIn[1] + gl_PositionIn[2]) / 3.0;
        sumN.xyz = (n[0].xyz + n[1].xyz + n[2].xyz) / 3.0;
        sumN.w = 0.0;
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * sumV;
        EmitVertex();
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * (sumV + (sumN * l_length));
        EmitVertex();
        EndPrimitive();
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < gl_VerticesIn; ++i)
        {
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_PositionIn[i];
            EmitVertex();
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * (gl_PositionIn[i] + (vec4(n[i], 0) * l_length));
            EmitVertex();
            EndPrimitive();
        }
    }

    // Tangent
    color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    if (mode == 1)
    {
        sumV = (gl_PositionIn[0] + gl_PositionIn[1] + gl_PositionIn[2]) / 3.0;
        sumN.xyz = (t[0].xyz + t[1].xyz + t[2].xyz) / 3.0;
        sumN.w = 0.0;
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * sumV;
        EmitVertex();
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * (sumV + (sumN * l_length));
        EmitVertex();
        EndPrimitive();
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < gl_VerticesIn; ++i)
        {
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_PositionIn[i];
            EmitVertex();
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * (gl_PositionIn[i] + (vec4(t[i], 0) * l_length));
            EmitVertex();
            EndPrimitive();
        }
    }

    // biTangent
    color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    if (mode == 1)
    {
        sumV = (gl_PositionIn[0] + gl_PositionIn[1] + gl_PositionIn[2]) / 3.0;
        sumN.xyz = (b[0].xyz + b[1].xyz + b[2].xyz) / 3.0;
        sumN.w = 0.0;
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * sumV;
        EmitVertex();
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * (sumV + (sumN * l_length));
        EmitVertex();
        EndPrimitive();
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < gl_VerticesIn; ++i)
        {
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_PositionIn[i];
            EmitVertex();
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * (gl_PositionIn[i] + (vec4(b[i], 0) * l_length));
            EmitVertex();
            EndPrimitive();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part and how is not working then? What is the expected output?

Comment: In mode 1, it draws the normal in red, the tangent in green and the biTangent in purple.. 
If not in mode 1, it draws only the red normal... I'm very confused why that is.

Comment: If you are going to vote down my question, at least say why!

Comment: It wasn't me. However I'm presuming it is because of the vagueness of the question.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't think it was you.. I did need to be a little clearer I guess.
I still have not got this to work. I even put for/next and called each item based on the index of the for/next loop. I guess its just one of those things that makes you go.. hmmmmmmm.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally..
 I set the paramiter wrong.. It was at 6 but it needs to be 18 to work:
It was this line:

```
Gl.glProgramParameteriEXT(shader, Gl.GL_GEOMETRY_VERTICES_OUT_EXT, 18)
```

End result...

[image]